# mkdir command doesn't work using exec() in PHP

Tags: php, shell, unix, scripting, exec

This is strange. Although basic commands such as ls, date, whoami are working. I cant seem to make a directory using the mkdir command using exec

```
$output=exec("mkdir helloworld");
```

Also it is worth asking, if such an error is occurring. is there any parameter or i can use to capture this error. Like the example below?

```
exec("mkdir helloworld 2>&1",$output,$return_val)
if($return_val !== 0) 
echo "there was an error"
```

Comment: Any particular reason why not to use `mkdir` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) ?

Comment: Please define: `doesn't work`. Have you checked the permissions? Have you checked the path?

Comment: Im making a web-based terminal..that executes UNIX commands on the browser

Comment: @Bobby I can make the directory using mkdir helloworld command in terminal. Why not using exec() ? 

Perhaps because i am using root in the terminal. and www-data using the exec command from the browser?

Comment: Did you check the $output? It should give you more information about what happened there. I bet for the unsufficient priviledges.

Comment: @user478636: Are you running the command under the same user as the Web-Server? Also, please tell me that this is just a practice...in production such solutions can turn really ugly really quick.

Comment: this is indeed practice....we are learning Linux in our course.
the user 'www-data' which i believe is the Apache web user doesn't have rights...how do i assign full rights

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is most probably due to missing file priviliges of the user that is executing the code (the apache-user in many cases).
If you add " 2>&1" to your command, you can also see the error output in $output